# Pass data using ThreadLocal<T> across different classes

Tags: c#, thread-local-storage

Edited my Question with more info below regarding the "another thread" after usr pointed out that my question wasn't clear.

How can I pass data using the `ThreadLocal<T>` across different classes?

Basically, I need to pass the LogContext info from a class in the Webservice to a `TraceExtension:SoapExtension` class (The TraceExtension is to log request/responses of another WebService that this WebService calls).

Since the functionality runs on another thread and not the thread that initiated the request, I cannot get it from a `ServiceContext:IExtension <InstanceContext>`
, that I would normally use for such a thing.

I have a working implementation using the `Thread.GetNamedDataSlot()` way, but in performance testing we found there is a memory leak problem. (Yes, I have called the `Thread.FreeNamedDataSlot()` and the problem persisted). This lead to MS post http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2540745 that a leak problem may exist, but in our current timeframe for the release it will not be possible to deploy the fix on all the production servers. The work around suggested is to use the System.Threading.ThreadLocal class.

All the resources/examples I have found so far have instances of ThreadLocal in the same class and of Parallelism and PLinq. An example of initializing/setting data in one class and retrieving it from another will be very helpful.
Any other way of passing data to the `TraceExtension : SoapExtension` will also be equally helpful.

We are a bit tight on schedule and any help will be much appreciated.

Edit with more info:

The thread of our Webservice on which the request comes creates a new Thread on which we run some background processing, while returning the necessary response. 
The new Thread invokes calls to other backend web services. We also have a TraceExtension class to trace the Request/Response to the backend web serivces.
We pass the LogContext info from the original Thread to the method on the new Thread using a `ContextInfo : ISynchronizeInvoke`.

The problem is getting the LogContext object From the class invoking the backend webservice call To the TraceExtension class (which runs on the new Thread and not the original Thread on which the client request came having the `ServiceContext:IExtension<InstanceContext>` which does hold the LogContext)

Comment: "Since the functionality runs on another thread and not the thread that initiated the request" it seems that you *cannot* use thread-local state because you need to pass data across threads. What am I missing?

Comment: When the new thread is created, I'm passing the context info to it using a ContextInfo : ISynchronizeInvoke. So I receive the LogContext in the new thread, but later when I make the call from this new thread to a backend WebService, I wasn't being able to pass the LogContext to the TraceExtension class tracing the backend webservice.
Since, we do not do background processing for other stuff on a "different" thread, we could get the LogContext from the ServiceContext:IExtension <InstanceContext>. But it wasn't happening in this case and that's what I actually meant by "runs on another thread".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [ThreadStaticAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I must have looked at it atleast 10 times and discarded it thinking I could not use it since it is static and would not be able to store values from different instances.It is amazing that I have been reading only what my mind wanted to believe until you mentioned to use it. Thanks Moho.